# require a library module in requirejs

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs

I want to execute `Nav.init(), Nav1.init()` both after dom ready so I call `DomReady` module inside `Nav, Nav1` each module before.

Now I try edit the code to call `DomReady` module before require them both, then just need to write one time but because there is a `require` parameter I don't know how should I do?
Does it like this `define(['require','DomReady!'], function (require, DomReady) {` ?

```
define(['DomReady!'], function (require, DomReady) {
  var Nav = require('custom/Nav');
  Nav.init();

  var Nav1 = require('custom/Nav1');
  Nav1.init();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
define(['DomReady!'], function (DomReady) {
  require(['custom/Nav'], function(Nav){
    Nav.init();   
  });
  

  require(['custom/Nav1'], function(Nav1){
    Nav1.init();   
  });
});
```